# jQuery - how do I add a class on li element when I click?

Tags: jquery, list, html, html-lists, addclass

I've found a lot of similar questions but unfortunately none really help with my problem...

I have a navigation list

```
<div class="nav-container">
     <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I want to give a class to the anchor tag (not the 'li') when I click on it. So far I have:

```
$(".nav-container li a").click(function(){
    $('.nav-container li a').removeClass('nav-active');
    $(this).addClass('nav-active');
})
```

It seems to add the class for a split second and then disappear.

I've managed to get the class to apply by using 'return false;' at the end but it stops the actual links from working all together.

I'm guessing one is cancelling the other out and it just needs some way to stop it... not quite sure how you do that (sorry - new to jQuery)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can sort my issue out :)

Answer (score 1):

For this example, the browser is reloading index.php or contact.php, so you may need to put the class logic on the server.

Your class is disappearing because the page is reloading and this new page has no knowledge of the old page event that triggered the change.

To solve this in Javascript alone, you would either need to:

- drop a cookie on the click event, then read it back on the page load to re-apply the class on the new page, or
- load the contents of each page asynchronously

However, since you currently have contact.php and index.php as two independent pages, it may be easier just to hard code the class into the markup of each page.

Comment: Thank you @PassKit, I'm not sure I understand however... I'm using WAMP which usually works fine with these kind of things?

Comment: It's not a WAMP or stack issue. Let's say you are on index.php and you click 'Contact'.  The Javascript event triggers, the class changes but at the same time, a request is sent to the server to fetch contact.php.  When contact.php loads, it is independent of index.php in that it does not know that contact.php has been clicked.